# Object factory with changing constructor parameters in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

I have a problem something like that.

```
IBase = interface
end;

TObjectType = ( otUnknown, otDesc1, otDesc2 );

TBase = class ( TInterfacedObject, IBase )
  private
    fType : TObjectType;
  public
    constructor create( type_ : TObjectType );
end;

TDesc1 = class ( TBase )
  public
    constructor create;
end;

TDesc2 = class ( TBase )
  public
    constructor create;
end;

TObjectFactory = class
  public
    function createInstance( key_ : string ) : IBase; virtual; abstract;
end;

TMyObjectFactory = class ( TObjectFactory )
  private
    fRegisteredTypes : TStringList;
  public
    function createInstance( key_ : string ) : IBase; override;

end;

EUnregisteredType = class ( Exception )
end;

constructor TBase.create( type_ : TObjectType );
begin
  inherited create;
  fType := type_;
  //...
end;

constructor TDesc1.create;
begin
  inherited create( otDesc1 );
  //...
end;

constructor TDesc2.create;
begin
  inherited create( otDesc2 );
  //...
end;

function TMyObjectFactory.createInstance( key_ : string ) : IBase;
var
  ndx : integer;
begin
  ndx := fRegisteredTypes.indexOf( key_ );
  if ( ndx > -1 ) then
    result := TBase( fRegisteredTypes.objects[ndx] ).create 
  else
    raise EUnregisteredType.create( key_ );
end;
```

As I read to implement the abstract factory design pattern I should create dynamic constructors and override it in descendants. But my constructor parameters differ in descendants (not any), so overwriting is not possible. Is there any way in this case to the abstract factory pattern or just the prototype design pattern works?

Comment: The code doesn't compile. Why did you post such code? There are solutions to your problem. Why don't you use a DI framework like spring?

Comment: This is just a pseudo code to draft the problem in concise form. Any valuable reflection in theme of DELPHI?

Comment: I cannot make any sense of that question

Comment: It wuold be much sensible if I write the definition/declaration parts separated in a compilable form? The question is : is there any solution to the object factory design pattern if the params of the descendents constructors difer from the ancestor's one? Or I should create the copy methods/constructors to implement the prototype design pattern?

Comment: I removed the erroneous tags. Again. Please don't add tags that are not related to the question. So, for the prototype pattern the tag is [prototype-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototype-pattern). As far as object factory, perhaps you are looking for [factory-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factory-pattern). And again, aren't you looking for a DI framework like spring?

Comment: I'm writing an event driven DXF exporter in Delphi 7. The program dispatch messages to build the DXF DOM (for example create a line entity). But I want to create a flexible solution (not to wiring the available types inside the center of the code) so I thought I should use the FACTORY PATTERN (I have registereg the available types in a tstringlist from the outside) :) But the different constructor parameters in the derivation tree gave a lession to me. And as I mentioned I know a solution by the PROTOTYPE PATTERN, but I would like to avoid the creation of the copy methods/constructors.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Spring DI is not an abstract factory design pattern implementation. It is untestable/unmockable because of its global variable(s).  Just as like any other singleton design pattern implementations as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you are attempting, you need to use virtual constructors, which means you cannot have different parameters in the ancestor and derived constructors.  However, you can make the `fX` member be protected instead of private so derived constructors can access it directly.

Try something more like this:

```
type
  X = (x1, x2, ...);

  TBase = class ( TInterfacedObject, IBase )
  protected
    fX : X;
  public
    constructor Create; virtual;
  end;

  TBaseClass = class of TBase;

  TDesc1 = class ( TBase )
  public
    constructor Create; override;
  end;

  TDescr2 = class ( TBase )
  public
    constructor Create; override;
  end;

  TObjectFactory = class
  private
    fRegisteredTypes : TStringList;
  public
    function createInstance( key_ : string ) : IBase;
    ...
  end;

...

constructor TBase.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  ...
end;

constructor TDesc1.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  fX := x1;
  ...
end;

constructor TDesc2.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  fX := x2;
  ...
end;

function TObjectFactory.createInstance( key_ : string ) : IBase;
var
  ndx : Integer;
begin
  ndx := fRegisteredTypes.indexOf( key_ );
  if ( ndx = -1 ) then
    raise EUnregisteredType.Create( key_ );
  Result := TBaseClass( fRegisteredTypes.objects[ndx] ).Create;
end;
```

Comment: This is a really logical solution! I am ashamed that I did not realize. But instead I will just create a protected setter method. Thanks a lot for the idea!